# What's the best practice to route request to particular EC2 instance behind AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have one API which needs to check some status for each instance behind ELB. So, whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using path-based routing for Application Load Balancer. You can create a listener with rules to forward requests based on the URL path. 
This is the link to the original document by AWS :
'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html'

Comment: For this approach, it means we have to create target Group for each instance?

Comment: You just need to add a listeners